# htaccess redirects not working in relative paths

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make a redirection from all files to a template file. But redirects only works when I specify an URL

For example:

**Does not work (it does not redirects)**

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /template.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Works (redirects to http://domain.com/versioned/template.php?page=index.html)**

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/versioned/template.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And the second option is change the URL in the browser. I need to keep the original URL.

Thanks

The problem is with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

If I quit this, it works, but instead of returning the current file in URL, it returns always template.php

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? e.g. where does `template.php` live in the directory?

Comment: in "/home/juan/Escritorio/www/versioned/gestionClaro/"

now it works with

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ template.php?file?=$1 [L]

. I can't understadnd why the previous isn't even responding with a 404

Comment: Now instead of giving me in $_GET["file"] the current URL, it returns always template.php

Answer (score 0):

If the htaccess file is in the `versioned` directory, you don't want the leading slash in the rule's target:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) template.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The relative URL-path in this rule's target, `template.php?page=$1`, tells mod_rewrite to rewrite the request to this URL-path that is within the path that the htaccess file is in. When you had the target as `/template.php?page=$1`, it assumed an absolute URL-path, which would be equivalent to: `http://domain.com/template.php?page=foo`.